# Default character encoding in java for inputStream of HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding

I am using java's `InputStream` of `HttpUrlConnection` to get body of an URL and write same to a file.
Things works fine on my laptop (Ubuntu/Centos Desktop version) but on server(centos 6.5 server edition), special characters, incoming in body gets garbled to question marks.
I tried to compare Java's `Charset.defaultCharset()` and `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`, both are same on laptop and server.

Can anyone please help me to find out what is different in laptop and server OS related to Character Encoding issue.

```
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
URL obj = new URL("http://www.Some URL That Has spl Char (eg. EN Dash)");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
```

Comment: show your code where you use InputStream

Answer (score 0):

In the headers the encoding are often given (connection.getContentEncoding() for instance, could be null). This is useful for text, to convert an InputStream to a Reader (InputStreamReader) and such.

If you are using InputStream/OutputStream, you are working with binary data - as is -, hence no corruption will occure. But you'll loose the header info, that might have said something about the encoding. You might want to store any data with a given encoding as UTF-8 for consistency. However in HTML the encoding may be given in the content.

---

***On the given code***

The input is encoded by the default. Which is quite variable by platform, and even user settings.
Better use an explicit encoding.

```
// Nice if the connection has in its headers an encoding
// or in Content-Type charset=...
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
if (encoding == null) {
    // Otherwise ISO-8859-1 is the HTTP standard, and
    // browsers extend ISO-8859-1 to Windows-1252.
    encoding = "Windows-1252";
}
Charset charset = Charset.forName(encoding);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), charset));
```

Of course writing the String of the StringBuilder to a media with the right encoding.

Comment: Thanks Joop, But this works fine on Desktop version of OS and I face issue only on server edition OS

Comment: @RohitVerma added the specification of the charset to the `InputStreamReader`. Otherwise the code is not suited for crossplatform usage for non-local data. The same hold for `OutputStreamWriter`. The question is, what encoding are those bytes in?

Comment: This is known that if specified charset it works fine. My question is to find what property or difference is creating this issue on server if charset is not explicitly mentioned.